# RPM Installation Excruciatingly Slow

Tags: linux, rpm

In one of my CentOS release 6.7 system with 2.6.32 kernel, I am observing that installation of rpm is very slow. This isn't the case usually. What could the issue? The system is idle. No CPU intensive application is running. `top`, `vmstat` outputs look fine.

```
root@blr# rpm -ivh SystemSupport-10.5.1.i386_centos_el6.rpm   

Preparing...     ########################################### [100%] 

1:SystemSupport  #######                                      (17%)
```

Its stuck at 17% for more than an hour now.

Any pointers in investigation this issue is sincerely appreciated.

`lsof -p $(pgrep -o rpm)` lists many entries. The one with the rpm I am trying to install is as:

```
rpm     2533 root    6r   REG    8,2 18375865 17481 /root/software/1.12.6.002_GA/SystemSupport-10.5.1.i386_centos_el6.rpm
rpm     2533 root    7u   REG    8,6    12288   853 /var/lib/rpm/Triggername
rpm     2533 root    8uW  REG    8,6        0   610 /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock
rpm     2533 root    9r   REG    8,2 18375865 17481 /root/software/1.12.6.002_GA/SystemSupport-10.5.1.i386_centos_el6.rpm

[root@blr]# iostat -x -d 1
Linux 2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.i686 (blr)  01/06/2017      _i686_  (24 CPU)

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.30     6.70    1.22    1.66    29.17    66.92    33.32    15.16 5257.02  117.73 9029.41 318.10  91.73

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    2.00     0.00    40.00    20.00     5.12 1622.00    0.00 1622.00 500.00 100.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     1.00    0.00    2.00     0.00    16.00     8.00     5.25 3247.00    0.00 3247.00 500.00 100.00
```

dmesg:

```
 INFO: task rs:main Q:Reg:1961 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
      Not tainted 2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.i686 #1
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
rs:main Q:Reg D c1ed5364     0  1961      1 0x00000080
 f44e7aa0 00000082 00000c88 c1ed5364 c1ed5364 00000000 00000000 c0469e95
 c15f8c80 00000557 02adfee8 00000557 c0b9bb20 c0b9bb20 f44e7d48 c0b9bb20
 c0b97364 c0b9bb20 f44e7d48 c1ed5364 00001084 00000000 c1a77824 f5244d40
Call Trace:
 [<c0469e95>] ? local_bh_enable+0x75/0x90
 [<c057171c>] ? __find_get_block+0x8c/0x1c0
 [<c04913da>] ? ktime_get_ts+0xea/0x120
 [<c08789a9>] ? io_schedule+0x59/0xa0
 [<c04f4c7c>] ? sync_page+0x2c/0x40
 [<c087909f>] ? __wait_on_bit_lock+0x3f/0x90
 [<c04f4c50>] ? sync_page+0x0/0x40
 [<c04f4c30>] ? __lock_page+0x80/0x90
 [<c0485c80>] ? wake_bit_function+0x0/0x60
 [<c04f5cac>] ? find_lock_page+0x3c/0x70
 [<c04f5d1d>] ? grab_cache_page_write_begin+0x3d/0xc0
 [<f7f2df84>] ? ext4_da_write_begin+0xc4/0x260 [ext4]
 [<f7f27309>] ? ext4_mark_iloc_dirty+0x349/0x570 [ext4]
 [<c04f5563>] ? generic_file_buffered_write+0x103/0x2c0
 [<c04f6344>] ? __generic_file_aio_write+0x1e4/0x540
 [<c0456656>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x206/0x3c0
 [<c04f6717>] ? generic_file_aio_write+0x77/0xf0
 [<c0543945>] ? do_sync_write+0xd5/0x120
 [<c0485be0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<c04c0736>] ? audit_filter_rules+0x16/0xde0
 [<c0580139>] ? inotify_dentry_parent_queue_event+0x89/0xc0
 [<c05c49fc>] ? security_file_permission+0xc/0x10
 [<c0543b16>] ? rw_verify_area+0x66/0xe0
 [<c0543870>] ? do_sync_write+0x0/0x120
 [<c0543c30>] ? vfs_write+0xa0/0x190
 [<c08793e1>] ? mutex_lock+0x11/0x40
 [<c05447eb>] ? sys_write+0x4b/0xa0
 [<c0409bbf>] ? sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
[root@AG1K-1 stgadm]#
```

> smartctl

```
  smartctl 5.43 2012-06-30 r3573 [i686-linux-2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.i686] (local build)
  2 Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net
  3
  4 === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
  5 Device Model:     16GB CompactFlash Card
  6 Serial Number:    20150511    00000017
  7 Firmware Version: CFMAD01A
  8 User Capacity:    16,391,340,032 bytes [16.3 GB]
  9 Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
 10 Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
 11 ATA Version is:   7
 12 ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
 13 Local Time is:    Fri Jan  6 20:31:51 2017 MYT
 14 SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
 15 SMART support is: Enabled
 16
 17 === START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
 18 SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
 19
 20 General SMART Values:
 21 Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
 22                                         was never started.
 23                                         Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
 24 Total time to complete Offline
 25 data collection:                (    0) seconds.
 26 Offline data collection
 27 capabilities:                    (0x00)         Offline data collection not supported.
 28 SMART capabilities:            (0x0002) Does not save SMART data before
 29                                         entering power-saving mode.
 30                                         Supports SMART auto save timer.
 31 Error logging capability:        (0x00) Error logging NOT supported.
 32                                         No General Purpose Logging support.
 33
 34 SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
 35 Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
 36 ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
 37  12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0200   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
 38 160 Unknown_Attribute       0x0200   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3
 39 161 Unknown_Attribute       0x0200   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       37
 40 162 Unknown_Attribute       0x0200   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       43
 41 163 Unknown_Attribute       0x0200   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       9355
 42 164 Unknown_Attribute       0x0200   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       9050
 43 165 Unknown_Attribute       0x0200   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       9050
 44 241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0200   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
 45
 46 SMART Error Log not supported
 47 Error SMART Error Self-Test Log Read failed: scsi error aborted command
 48 Smartctl: SMART Self Test Log Read Failed
 49 Device does not support Selective Self Tests/Logging
```

`strace` output. The following keeps recurring:

```
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
getuid32()                              = 0
getuid32()                              = 0
chown32("/usr/local/lr/support/SystemSupport/10.5.1/Python/lib/python2.4/distutils/bcppcompiler.pyo;586f8d75", 0, 0) = 0
chmod("/usr/local/lr/support/SystemSupport/10.5.1/Python/lib/python2.4/distutils/bcppcompiler.pyo;586f8d75", 0644) = 0
utime("/usr/local/lr/support/SystemSupport/10.5.1/Python/lib/python2.4/distutils/bcppcompiler.pyo;586f8d75", [2016/10/24-19:22:15, 2016/10/24-19:22:15]) = 0
getuid32()                              = 0
lstat64("/usr/local/lr/support/SystemSupport/10.5.1/Python/lib/python2.4/distutils/bcppcompiler.pyo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=8379, ...}) = 0
rename("/usr/local/lr/support/SystemSupport/10.5.1/Python/lib/python2.4/distutils/bcppcompiler.pyo;586f8d75", "/usr/local/lr/support/SystemSupport/10.5.1/Python/lib/python2.4/distutils/bcppcompiler.pyo") = 0
umask(0777)                             = 022
open("/usr/local/lr/support/SystemSupport/10.5.1/Python/lib/python2.4/distutils/ccompiler.py;586f8d75", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As show by `smartctl`, the disk is a very small 16 GB CompactFlash card.
Executing an `hdparm -t /dev/sda` shows no results, so the problem seems related to the CF card. This seems confirmed by `iowait` showing 100% disk use even with very few read/write operations.

Flash memory are strange beasts: they are very fast **until** all page/blocks are written. After this point, any additional write incours in a read/modify/write or read/delete/write scenario, bringing performance to an halt. To avoid this problem, SSDs generally have background garbage routines and/or expose the TRIM command to explicitly clear unused blocks.

I strongly suspect your CF card have neither of them. Alternatively, maybe it is gone bad. In both cases, the safest approach is to replace it (with something bigger, perhaps).

Comment: When I run a simple 'C' doe that does a file write and read operations things go fine. How could this I/O go fine?

Comment: Because very small writes can be completed by a single block erase/reprogramming. Multiple writes are much more heavier for an used/bad CF card.

Comment: Hmm. I find it quite suspicious that a CF card that's supposedly been in use for some time is reporting zero LBAs written. Everything in the SMART data is now suspect. I was already pretty suspicious that the drive had gone bad before seeing that it was a CF and before seeing SMART data. But CF drives never were very reliable to begin with. Best to replace this with some small old SSD or something.

Answer (score 2):

Run `strace` or `lsof` on the process to see where it is stuck. It is not a common thing.

```
strace -f -p $(pgrep -o rpm)
lsof -p $(pgrep -o rpm)
```

Comment: I have edited question with `lsof -p $(pgrep -o rpm)` information